# What are CorrelationExtractionRules and CorrelationBinding attributes in web test files

Tags: automated-testing, visualstudio

What is the purpose of the `<CorrelationExtractionRules>` tag and the `CorrelationBinding="..."` attribute within the `<QueryStringParameter ...>` tag within a Visual Studio 2013 ".webtest" file?

The recorded web test for the web site I am testing has several requests that each has several extraction rules within the `<CorrelationExtractionRules>` tags. There are also many query string parameters that have `CorrelationBinding="..."` attributes where the `...` is the same name as in a correlation extraction rule.

The web test is not working as I desire. So I have recorded additional versions of the same test to try and find the important differences and hence the identify the fault. When I use a text file compare program on these ".webtest" files there are big differences in the correlation items. Are these differences significant? Can I just ignore the correlation items?